# PHP Warning in QueryBuilder file

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii2

After executing `service php5-fpm restart` on my  Ubuntu server Yii2 application gives me an error in a QueryBuilder.php file

```
strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

On this line

```
if (strpos($column, '(') === false) {
  $column = $this->db->quoteColumnName($column);
}
```

Comment: This means the value in $column is not a string, it is an array. The strpos function expects argument #1 to be a string and is issuing you with an error/warning. Use var_dump($column); to identify the contents of $column. Without more code relevant to $column, no-one can help you fix this problem.

Comment: But everything was ok before executing this command. And QueryBuilder.php is a internal hard coded yii2 file.

Comment: If you could provide the full stack trace, or even just the full path to the file this error occurs in, you'll likely find it is within a method in the Querybuilder class, that your code call from elsewhere. The problem may stem from the code before this code... if that makes sense. The only sure fire way to tell, is using var_dump($varName); until you trace where the $column variable is generated and passed as an array, instead of a string. Without more code, there is little anyone can do for you I'm afraid.

Comment: Please show the all the code and not only a few row. $column where it comes from ?